# Filtering in MVC

Tags: sql, model-view-controller

Im new to MVC. How can i filter and get all the records displayed related to a particular dataitem. Eg. If i click to Id =2 i want to display all items which has id=2. Please could anyone help

Comment: MVC in which language ?

Comment: pass that id in an Action return the result in a view ;)

Comment: Thanks Rafalon and Thushar.Im using Entity Framework and C# language. Ive tried passing the ID but its working only for a single item. But when Im using list it showing error. Could you please give an example. Sorry im a total beginner

Answer (score 0):

In your controller, you want to use LINQ. For example:

```
public ActionResult GetListOfSomething()
{
  var context = new MyDataContext();
  var model= new MyModel();      
  model.ItemList = context.MyObject.Where(x => x.SomeProperty == "SomeValue").ToList();
  return View(model);
}
```

This is a pretty simple example, but illustrates the concepts.